# Gráfica en Highcharts PHP Con Datos de Mysql

Tags: php, mysqli, phpmyadmin, php5, highcharts

Hola estoy tratando de crear una gráfica de resultados con datos traídos de una tabla en bd mysql el problema esta en que quiero que la imagen no tenga esas animaciones que se hacen al pasar el mause, sino que muestre todos los resultados incluida la imagen, luego de trae los datos de la bd con la consulta. Esto lo necesito así porque trae ademas de nombres y numero de votos la imagen. así como se ve la imagen por donde pasa el ratón las muestre todas sin necesidad de pasar el mause.....
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El tipo de gráfico BÁSICO DE COLUMNAS que tomé y la consulta que realizo para que salgan los campos nombres,grado, categoría e imagenes pero no logro q salgan las tres imagenes sin necesidad de pasar el mause.. En eso es q necesito que me ayuden

xAxis:{categories:[ <?php
$consulta = "SELECT a.nombre, g.grado, c.categoria, r.voto, a.foto
FROM resultados AS r
INNER JOIN aspirante AS a ON r.id_aspi = a.id_asp
INNER JOIN grado AS g ON a.id_grado = g.id_grado
INNER JOIN categoria AS c ON a.id_cat = c.id_cat";

```
                    $result = mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);
                        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                         {

                                    ?>
                                       "<?php echo $row['nombre'] ?>   <?php echo $row['grado'] ?>  <?php echo $row['categoria'] ?>  <?php echo "<img src=img/" . $row['foto']?> ",

                                  <?php   
                                      } 
                                 ?>
                            ]},
```

Comment: Si higcharts no trae una opción similar a lo que necesita, tendría que forzarlo, para ello tendría que conocer muy bien el uso de canvas y ver como contruye sobre higcharts.

Comment: Bienvenid@ a Stack Overflow en español, mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funciona el sitio y de paso obtener tu primera medalla. Añade tu código y lo que has intentado y seguramente podrán ayudarte.

Comment: http://www.pchart.net/